# how to register a addin for vs2008 

Tags: com, atl, visual-c++-2008

I'm a newer about COM. I want to write a plugin that locate in vs2008 
toolbar(not toolbox).

I created an ATL project. It gived me some default codes. so i could generate a DLL. Through this way, I can add this plugin  to ToolBox by TOOLs->choose tool items->COM components. But I want to add this into toolbar. So how should i do.

I add some regester info in rgs file, as follow:

```
HKCU{ NoRemove SOFTWARE   {
NoRemove Microsoft
{
  NoRemove VisualStudio
  {
    NoRemove 9.0
    {
      NoRemove AddIns
      {
        ForceRemove PiSvr.CalcPi
        {
          val CommandLineSafe  = d '0'
          val CommandPreload   = d '1'
          val Description      = s 'Sample Common Add-In'
          val FriendlyName     = s 'Sample Common Add-In'
          val LoadBehavior     = d '1'           
        }
      }
    }
  }
}  }}
```

But when I started the vs2008, it told me no such interface supported. error number:80004002

Comment: Thanks for reminding me .I didn't see the FAQ before, so I didn't know the rules clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The add-in connection is in registry under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\AddIns` and your script looks like correct. Note you can always use `regedit` to check if the corresponding registry item is there in registry too, not just in your script.

`0x80004002` is `E_NOINTERFACE` and what is probably taking place is that Visual Studio is trying to instantiate and initialize your add-in but it lacks a mandatory interface implemetnation, and Visual Studio aborts the attempt.

To troubleshoot this, debug your add-in and check what interfaces are queried, esp. those for which you return error code and indicate their absence.